# Get current Topic

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get the current Post? I'm trying to redirect to my current post where im sending my vote but this method that i created redirects to Oldest Post created by this user.

```
public function ScoreAction(Request $request){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $idPoster = $request->request->get('id_posterUser');
    $positive= $request->request->get('positive');
    $negative= $request->request->get('negative');

    $user=  $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneById($idPoster);


    $topic = $em->getRepository(Topic::class)->findOneByUser($user->getId());

    $score = $usuari->getReputation();

    if ($positive!= null) {
        $score = $score + 1;
    }
    if($negative!= null){
         $score = $score - 1;
    }

    $user->setReputation($score );
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

     $redirect = $this->generateUrl('discutea_forum_post', array('slug' => $topic->getSlug())); 

return $this->redirect($redirect);


}
```

Edit: Added my Solution.

**Solution** :

```
 public function ScoreAction(Request $request){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $idTopic = $request->request->get('id_topic');       

        $idPoster = $request->request->get('id_poster');

        $positive= $request->request->get('positive');
        $negative= $request->request->get('negatiu');

        $user=  $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneById($idPoster); 

        $topic = $em->getRepository(Topic::class)->findOneById($idTopic); 


        $score= $user->getReputation();

        if ($positive!= null) {
            $score= $score+ 1;
        }
        if($negative!= null){
             $score= $score- 1;
        }

        $user->setReputation($score);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();


        $redirect = $this->generateUrl('discutea_forum_post', array('slug' => $topic->getSlug())); 

        return $this->redirect($redirect);
    }
```

Comment: what is puntuacio, what is topic ? show a bit more code

Comment: Sorry I forgot to translate it ill edit.

Comment: 1. Have you checked if `id_posterUser` is valid? 2. Is the topic slug unique?
 3. Problem with another action with path `discutea_forum_post`, show the code.

Comment: @miikes Yes is valid i checked and the topic slug is unique too. I'dont understand the 3rd question. Which code should I show ?

Comment: Code of the action handling path `discutea_forum_post`.

Comment: @miikes Yes I did it to set the new score to user. I added the postaction on the main question.

Comment: you do a getPosts, but you want only one post, is that right ?

Comment: Are you always want to score last Topic?

Comment: I wanted to redirect where the current page when I send a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching topic by user:

```
$topic = $em->getRepository(Topic::class)->findOneByUser($user->getId());
```

`findOneByUser` - builds query `WHERE user.id = :user_id LIMIT 1`

For get the last Topic you need to add ordering.

```
$topic = $em->getRepository(Topic::class)->findOneBy(
    array('user' => $user), 
    array('id' => 'desc')
);
```

Comment: Yesss thats it !!! I really apreciate yout help. Thanks all for helping.

Comment: The only problem is that i can't vote other user that aren't the author of a post.

Comment: So you need to change action logic. Pass the Topic id in the request or pass it in path and get the Topic by it's real id, not only the last author Topic.

Comment: With that findOneByUser looks like you're gonna do WHERE user = :user where user is an User entity, call it findOneByUserId or send the actual entity and keep the name

Comment: Okk I solved. Ill update with my solution. Thanks all for help.